# convert binary image 30m to 60m (google earth engine)

Tags: javascript, google-earth-engine

When im converting the 30m binary image to 60m. As a result im getting binary image.
But the desired image is having pixel values from 0 to 4. as 4 pixels are compiled when scaled to 60m.
for example: if two out of four pixels are 1, the pixel value in 60m should be 2. but i dont know why the result is again binary image.

Comment: Please see [ask] and possibly add your code or what you've tried

Answer (score 0):

Resampling on the GEE is done using the nearest neighbour method by default, which is why your resampled image remains binary. It sounds like you are looking for bilinear resampling, which you have to specify at some point in your workflow using the `resample()` function. I can expand on this if you include some reproducible code.